# PHP preg replace duplicate words in string if more than three

Tags: php, string, duplicates, preg-replace, cpu-word

I'm new to PHP. I would like to replace a string with specific duplicate words if more than three into two like below?

```
$wordToCheck = "abc";
$string = "abc abc abc abc Hello World abc abc abc My name is abc"
```

The result will be:

```
$outString = "abc abc Hello World abc abc My name is abc"
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace more than 2 consecutive same word with the following pattern that uses a backreference to the capture group 1 *(i.e. `\1`)*:

```
$pattern = '~\b(\w+) \1 \K\1(?: \1)*\b ?~';
$replacement = '';

$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Note that since the `\K` removes all that have been matched on the left from the match result, the two first occurences are not replaced.

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/aZ2jQ2/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "abc abc abc abc Hello World abc abc abc My name is abc";
print preg_replace("/abc abc abc( abc)*/","abc abc",$string);
```

Comment: +1 It is a good approach, not different than mine, but it works only for the word "abc"

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's explode like this:
`$wordArray = explode ( " ", $string);`

$wordArray will now contain one element for each space-delimited word in the original string.

You could then say something like:

```
$i = 0;
while ($wordArray[$i] == $wordToCheck) {
    $i++;
}
```

At that point, $i will tell you how many occurrences of $wordToCheck are at the beginning of the string.  After that, PHP's `array_shift` will remove elements from the front of the array, and, after you've shifted out enough words to leave only two, the `implode` function will turn the array back into a string.

Edited to add: I have not used regular expressions; I'm not sure how to do that, and I *am* sure you don't need to.

Edited again: This has been tested, and will work even if the first "word" of the string is not $wordToCheck:

```
<?php
$wordToCheck = "abc";
$string = "abc abc abc abc Hello World abc abc abc My name is abc";
$wordArray = explode ( " ", $string);
$i = 0;
while ($wordArray[$i] == $wordToCheck) {
    $i++;
}
for ($j=0; $j < $i-2; $j++) {
   array_shift($wordArray);
}
$string = implode(" ",$wordArray);
echo $string;
?>
```